# Java bypass proxy programmatically apache

Tags: java, apache, amazon-web-services, proxy

**Background**

I am using [AWS Java SDK for SQS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sqs/AmazonSQSClient.html) to read a message from a local queue. I am using [ElasticMQ](https://github.com/adamw/elasticmq) for my local queue.

```
@Test
public void readMessageFromQueue() {

    AWSCredentialsProviderChain credentialsProvider = new AWSCredentialsProviderChain(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain());
    ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();

    AmazonSQSClient sqsClient = new AmazonSQSClient(credentialsProvider, clientConfiguration);
    sqsClient.setEndpoint("http://127.0.0.1:9324/queue");
    ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest("queue1").withMaxNumberOfMessages(10);

    ReceiveMessageResult receiveMessageResult = sqsClient.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest);
    List<Message> sqsMessages = receiveMessageResult.getMessages();

}
```

This works perfectly until I am connected to my internet via proxy (at work)

I then get a `504` as it tries to route my localhost via my proxy.

**Question**

How do I bypass my proxy for my localhost programmatically in Java?

I have tried the following to no avail

```
System.setProperty("NO_PROXY", "127.0.0.1");
System.setProperty("proxySet", "false");
System.setProperty("proxyHost", "");
System.setProperty("proxyPort", "");
System.setProperty("no_proxy", "127.0.0.1");
System.setProperty("http.no_proxy", "127.0.0.1");
System.setProperty("http.proxySet", "false");
```

The only thing that works is adding `127.0.0.1` to bypass proxy in Mac Network Settings.

[image: localhost in bypass proxy]

I have also tried `localhost` (oppose to `127.0.0.1`)

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting *http.nonProxyHosts*?

```
String nonProxyHosts = System.getProperty("http.nonProxyHosts");
nonProxyHosts = nonProxyHosts == null ? "127.0.0.1" : nonProxyHosts + "|127.0.0.1";
System.setProperty("http.nonProxyHosts", nonProxyHosts);
```

Comment: I very much appreciate your accept, resulted in two badges for me. Unfortunately, you dont have much content I could show my gratitude at. But whenever you have another great question, just drop me a note ;-)